# Prove that a function is total, surjective, injective and find its domain of definition

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $D =  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Let $f:P(N) \to P(N)$, $f(B) = B \triangle D$

I said that the image of this function is: $P(N)$, is that right?

It's pretty clear that this function is total because it's image is $P(N)$

How do I prove that this function is subjective and injective?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s total because its domain is all of $\wp(\Bbb N)$: for any $B\in\wp(\Bbb N)$ the set $B\mathop{\triangle}D$ is defined and is an element of $\wp(\Bbb N)$. When you say that its image is $\wp(\Bbb N)$, you’re claiming (without proof as yet) that $f$ is surjective. In order actually to prove that, you must show that if $B$ is any subset of $\Bbb N$, there is some $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $f(A)=B$. In order to prove that $f$ is injective, you must show that if $A,B\subseteq\Bbb N$, and $f(A)=f(B)$, then $A=B$.

Here’s a HINT for both parts: If $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, what is $f\big(f(A)\big)$?

Comment: $f(f(A)) = (A \triangle D) \triangle D = A$
So, if I say that Let $ A \in N$, 
$f(A) \in P(N)$,
I can't just say that $f(f(A)) = A$, because $f(A) \notin N$, can you please help me structure the proof? :| Because it seems logic in my head but when I try to write it it's just get confusing.

Comment: @FigureItOut: You don’t want $f(A)\in\Bbb N$: you want $f(A)\in\wp(\Bbb N)$, i.e., $f(A)\subseteq\Bbb N$, which it is. To show that $f$ is surjective, let $B\in\wp(\Bbb N)$. Then if you set $A=f(B)$, you’ll have $f(A)=f\big(f(B)\big)=B$, showing that $B$ is in the range of $f$. And since $B$ was an arbitrary element of $\wp(\Bbb N)$, this shows that $f$ is surjective. Now try to show that if $A,B\in\wp(\Bbb N)$, and $f(A)=f(B)$, then $A=B$. HINT: What happens if you apply the function $f$ to both sides of the equation $f(A)=f(B)$?